# Has Eclipse RAP a standard API

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

this question might sound a little bit weired... But I will try to explain:

I got an Android App, that makes calls against a RAP-Build Website (to that I only have access via Webbrowser).

Until now I am sending pure HTTP Requests for example:

```
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url + ";jsessionid=" + jsessionid
            + "?nocache=" + System.currentTimeMillis()
            + "&org.eclipse.swt.events.widgetSelected=w131"
            + "&requestCounter=" + (requestCounter++) + "&uiRoot=w1"
            + "&w1.cursorLocation.x=282" + "&w1.cursorLocation.y=148");
```

then I get back a lot of stuff like this:

```
var wm = org.eclipse.swt.WidgetManager.getInstance(); [...] ;
wm.add( w, "w17", true );[...];w.setCaption( "THIS IS WHAT I NEEED" );
```

Then I use some complex Regular Expressions to parse what I want and send back another post with the actions.

But to get to my question: Is there an easier way to do this? Does RAP perhaps have a build in API for such external requests oder does a JAVA Library exist, that makes communication with RAP easier.

I hope you did understand my problem - if not please leave a comment and I will try to explain it further.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/FAQ#How_to_access_the_HTTP_session_.2F_session_store.3F) you can see the example "How to provide download link?" You can change the example to work in your way providing custom service handler and using it from the Android App.